# Nested HashMap values are not getting stored in HashMap for unique keys

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, hashmap

I have created a nested HashMap inside a class as shown below. The problem here is when I call function XOXO for different CPID e.g. Profile1, Profile2 then HashMap stores only last profile value i.e. Profile2.

However, it is clear that I am storing inner HashMap PV into Outer HashMap CP for the different keys every time i.e. CPID (Profile1, Profile2)

```java
public class abc {
    public static HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> CP = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<String, String> PV = null;
    public void XOXO(CPID) {
        PV = new HashMap<>();
        String Value1 = Function.getText(5, 5);
        String Value2 = Function.getText(6, 6);
        //Note value at coordinate (5,5)/(6,6) is changing for diff CPID
        PV.put("AB", Value1);
        PV.put("CD", Value2);
        CP.put(CPID, PV);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{Profile1, {AB= 123, CD = 456}
{Profile2, {AB= 123, CD = 456}
```

Expected output:

```
{Profile1, {AB= 999, CD = 888}
{Profile2, {AB= 123, CD = 456}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, at the top you have this:

```
public Class ABC
```

However, `class` is lowercase. So it should look like this:

```
public class ABC
```

Also, over here:

```
PV.put("AB", "Value1")
PV.put("CD", "Value2")
```

You are entering `Value1` and `Value2` as `String`'s, not as variables, and you forgot the semicolons. So it should be this:

```
PV.put("AB", Value1);
PV.put("CD", Value2);
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out things and that is what I wanted to put it there but done mistakes while posting. however, the output remains the same.